# Listing the contents of a directory (Windows 7)

Tags: scheme, kawa

Using Kawa 1.14.

I have tried opening the directory as a file (because file-exists? reports #t), and using read-line to read the "contents", but it does not work. I get an "Access denied" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the source, I found **kawa\lib\files.scm**, which defines **directory-files**.

So, it is just a matter of:

```
(require <kawa.lib.files>)
(directory-files path)
```

Answer (score 0):

At the Java level, there are two ways to list directories. You can use [`File.list`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list--) or [`File.listFiles`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles--), or you can use [`Files.newDirectoryStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newDirectoryStream-java.nio.file.Path-).

At the Kawa level, having briefly grepped through the source, it doesn't seem to use *any* of those interfaces. So it doesn't look like there's a built-in way to list directories in Kawa. You would need to use Kawa's [Java method invocation](http://www.gnu.org/software/kawa/Method-operations.html) features to invoke one of the above interfaces.